# How to escape quotes in Jinja2 template in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I try to filter the key value pairs, however the values may be quoted and these may vary between `'` and `"`.

My data source looks like:

```ini
CONFIG='/etc/app/config'
LOG_FILE=/var/log/app.log
UPDATE="auto"
```

The only way I have found is to define the quotes in a separate variable and then embed them in the string via string concatenation.

```yaml
- name: find all key-values, correctly with separate variable
  debug:
    msg: "{{ env_data | regex_findall('^(\\w+)=' ~ qc ~ '(.*?)' ~ qc ~ '$', multiline=True) }}"
  vars:
    qc: '[''"]?'
```

Correct result:

```
TASK [find all key-values, correctly with separate variable] *******************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [ "CONFIG",   "/etc/app/config" ],
        [ "LOG_FILE", "/var/log/app.log" ],
        [ "UPDATE",   "auto" ]
    ]
}
```

**Is there a way to embed both quotes directly into the string (with correct escaping) without having to define separate variable and act via string concatenation?**

In general, the problem can probably be broken down to the output of both quotes from a Jinja2 string, embedded into Yaml (Ansible).

---

#### Attempt for all my values

```yaml
# playbook.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    env_data: |
      CONFIG='/etc/app/config'
      LOG_FILE=/var/log/app.log
      UPDATE="auto"

  tasks:
    # see below
```

I had hoped for success with this variant, unfortunately in vain:

```yaml
- name: find all key-values, fails - single quotes not recognized
  debug:
    msg: "{{ env_data | regex_findall('^(\\w+)=[''\"]?(.*?)[''\"]?$', multiline=True) }}"
```

Result:

```
TASK [find all key-values, fails - single quotes not recognized] ***************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [ "CONFIG",   "'/etc/app/config'" ],
        [ "LOG_FILE", "/var/log/app.log" ],
        [ "UPDATE",   "auto" ]
    ]
}
```

#### Failed attempts for output of both quotes

- ```yaml
  quotes: "{{ '\"''' }}"
  ```

  Result: `"`, single quote is missing
- ```yaml
  quotes: '{{ ''"'''' }}'
  ```

  Error: *An unhandled exception occurred while templating*
- ```yaml
  quotes: '{{ ''"\'''' }}'
  ```

  Error: *An unhandled exception occurred while templating*
- ```yaml
  quotes: >-
    {{ '"''' }}
  ```

  Error: *An unhandled exception occurred while templating*
- ```yaml
  quotes: >-
    {{ "\"'" }}
  ```

  Error: *An unhandled exception occurred while templating*

Comment: What's the real purpose? If the data is in the ansible code, just format it correctly in the first place.

Comment: This data is the result fram a `command` as `stdout`, so it's not possible to "just format it correctly".

Comment: Sure it's possible.  Use `shell` instead, and pipe the output to `| sed 's/=/: /' > vars.yml`.  Then use the `vars_file` module.

Answer (score 2):

Having gotten clarification that the OP is dealing with the `stdout` from a `command` module call.  So...

Replace the `command` with `shell`, and change the format to YAML:

```
- name: Get results of process
  shell: "my_command | sed 's/=/: /' > vars.yml"
```

Now read the file:

```
- name: Read file
  vars_file: vars.yml
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

- Parse the data first. For example,

```yaml
  regex_quotes: '[''"]'
  env_data_lists: "{{ env_data.splitlines()|
                      map('regex_replace', regex_quotes, '')|
                      map('split', '=')|
                      list  }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  env_data_lists:
  - - CONFIG
    - /etc/app/config
  - - LOG_FILE
    - /var/log/app.log
  - - UPDATE
    - auto
```

- Create a dictionary if you want to easily reference the items

```yaml
  env_data_dict: "{{ dict(env_data_lists) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  env_data_dict:
    CONFIG: /etc/app/config
    LOG_FILE: /var/log/app.log
    UPDATE: auto
```

- Then, you can format the lists as you like. The simplest option is using the filters to [format data: YAML and JSON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json). For example, the filter *to_nice_json*

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: env_data_lists|to_nice_json
```

gives

```yaml
  env_data_lists|to_nice_json: |-
    [
        [
            "CONFIG",
            "/etc/app/config"
        ],
        [
            "LOG_FILE",
            "/var/log/app.log"
        ],
        [
            "UPDATE",
            "auto"
        ]
    ]
```

- You can format the data on your own if you want to. For example,

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.yaml
        content: |
          ---
          [
          {% for i in env_data_lists %}
              [ "{{ i.0 }}", "{{ i.1 }}" ]{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}

          {% endfor %}
          ]
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test.yaml 
---
[
    [ "CONFIG", "/etc/app/config" ],
    [ "LOG_FILE", "/var/log/app.log" ],
    [ "UPDATE", "auto" ]
]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    env_data: |
      CONFIG='/etc/app/config'
      LOG_FILE=/var/log/app.log
      UPDATE="auto"

    regex_quotes: '[''"]'
    env_data_lists: "{{ env_data.splitlines()|
                        map('regex_replace', regex_quotes, '')|
                        map('split', '=')|
                        list  }}"
    env_data_dict: "{{ dict(env_data_lists) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: env_data_lists
    - debug:
        var: env_data_dict
    - debug:
        var: env_data_lists|to_nice_json
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.yaml
        content: |
          ---
          [
          {% for i in env_data_lists %}
              [ "{{ i.0 }}", "{{ i.1 }}" ]{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}

          {% endfor %}
          ]
```